Task Assigning problem in Timefold - Optaplanner
I am currently trying to model a problem in Timefold/Optaplanner very similar to the task assignment problem in the documentation or this problem. I am using a PlanningListVariable with a chained through time pattern.
Except that in my problem, tasks have to be assigned to 1 to N employees simultaneously.
The documentation tends to imply that it is possible, especially here, but it also states that planning list variables only support disjoint lists (but one of my tasks has to be assigned to multiple employees).
Do you have any advice on how to approach this problem?
I have already tried workarounds, such as:

Duplicating each tasks as many times as an employee is needed and updating the start time of all the simultaneous tasks via a ListVariableListener as indicated here.
Unfortunately, this causes score corruption in the undoMove, and as I understand it, we can't update an uncorrelated Planning Entity especially when multithreading.
Duplicating tasks and penalizing if the simultaneous tasks start more than X minutes apart. This is a very degraded solution and feels like it won't work in the long run.

Thank you for your time.
